# Having trouble properly evaluating a string with NSRegularExpression and NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I'm stuck on this problem for quite a while now and I couldn't figure out a proper solution with the usual google search. I'm trying to evaluate the format of a string, more precisely I'm checking to see if the string is a Canadian postal code or not.

So I started with this regex, thanks to [geeks with blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx)

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$
```

After that, I've created an instance of NSRegularExpression in such way:

`NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\\d{1}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];`

With added backslashes for escaping.

Then I made an `NSPredicate` with the regular expression

```
NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", regex];
```

And finally, I'm evaluating the string itself

```
[regextest evaluateWithObject:@"G2G 2S2"]
```

At that last line, an exception is thrown.

> NSInvalidArgumentException Can't create a regex expression from object
>
> NSRegularExpression: 0x81e1bb0 ^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}
>   *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$ 0x1.

I can't figure it out =/ I tested the regex itself with a [regex tester](http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp) and it's fine, and from what I checked with google that's how a string evaluation should be done. I'm at lost here. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try taking out all the ``{1}``s since they're unnecessary.

Comment: @acheong87 Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I tried that and unfortunately I still get the exception thrown in =/ but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `NSPredicate` the pattern is just a string, so this will work:

```
NSString *pattern = @"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\\d{1}$";

NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", pattern];

BOOL result = [regextest evaluateWithObject:@"G2G 2S2"];
```

Oh, and I agree that the `{1}`-parts should be removed - they just add clutter.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! However now I'm wondering why NSRegularExpression was acting up haha. But at least now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I explained the stuff about NSRegularExpression in my answer for details ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should directly use your pattern in the `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", pattern]` line, instead of passing an `NSRegularExpression` object.

(Besides, you can remove the `{1}` from your regular expression are they are not needed.)

```
NSString* pattern = @"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z] *\\d[A-Z]\\d$";
NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", pattern];

if ([regextest evaluateWithObject:@"G2G 2S2"]) ...
```

To perform regular expressions on iOS, you either use `NSPredicate` class or the `NSRegularExpression` but not both:

- `NSPredicate` is the simple case where you only need to check if a match is found.
- `NSRegularExpression` is much more complete and allows you to list all the matches, their position in the string, iterate over all the matches, perform replacements, etc.

---

If you wanted, you may use `NSRegularExpression` this way:

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z] *\\d[A-Z]\\d$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSUInteger nbFound = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:@"G2G 2S2" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,7)];
if (nbFound > 0) ...
```

But as you only want to check if the string match the pattern, and don't need more info (you don't need the range of the found string, nor to do replacements or extract subexpressions from the found string, etc), `NSPredicate` is sufficient for your usage, and should also be more efficient for a simple YES/NO test.